# How to combine custom hook for data fetching and context?

Tags: reactjs

I have a custom hook to fetch data on form submit

```
export const getIssues = ({ user, repo }) => {
  const [issues, setIssues] = useState([]);

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.get(`https://api.github.com/repos/${user}/${repo}/issues`)
      .then((response) => {
        setIssues(response.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };

  return {
    issues,
    onSubmit: handleInputChange,
  };
};
```

In my component I call it like this

```
const response = getIssues({ user: user.value, repo: repo.value })
  return (
    <form className={css['search-form']} {...response}>...</form>
)
```

The problem is that I want to get my `issues` value from the hook in another component. For that I wanted to use Context. But I have no idea how to do it.

I could call this function and pass it to `Provider`, but I can't call it without arguments. So I kind of stuck.

All the help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Since `getIssues` is a hook you should call it `useIssues` a linter should have complained about this. The `e.preventDefault` does not belong in the issues hook, since you provide values `user.value` and `repo.value` I assume your form sets these in some way so just calling `useIssues` should be enough.

Answer (score 2):

You are right by saying you need `React.Context` to handle this situation.

1. You need to wrap your components into this context.

```
import React from "react";

const IssuesStateContext = React.createContext();
const IssuesDispatchContext = React.createContext();

function issuesReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "setIssues": {
      return [...action.payload];
    }

    default: {
      throw new Error(`Unhandled action type: ${action.type}`);
    }
  }
}

function IssuesProvider({ children }) {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(issuesReducer, []);
  return (
    <IssuesStateContext.Provider value={state}>
      <IssuesDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
        {children}
      </IssuesDispatchContext.Provider>
    </IssuesStateContext.Provider>
  );
}

function useIssuesState() {
  const context = React.useContext(IssuesStateContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error("useIssuesState must be used within a IssuesProvider");
  }
  return context;
}
function useIssuesDispatch() {
  const context = React.useContext(IssuesDispatchContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error("useIssuesDispatch must be used within a IssuesProvider");
  }
  return context;
}

export { IssuesProvider, useIssuesState, useIssuesDispatch };
```

By using this separation in context you will be able to set issues coming from github in one component and render them in a completely different one.

Example:

App.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <IssuesProvider>
    <Component1 />
    <Component2 />
  </IssuesProvider>
)
```

Component 1

```
import React from 'react'
import { useIssuesDispatch } from './issues-context'

function Component1() {
  const dispatch = useIssuesDispatch()
  // fetch issues
  // .then dispatch({ type: 'setIssues', payload: response })

  // render
}
```

Component 2

```
import React from 'react'
import { useIssuesState } from './issues-context'

function Component2() {
  const issues = useIssuesState()

  // if issues.length > 0 ? render : null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a Issues context provider that will provide `{issues,useIssues}` where issues are the issues and useIssues is a function that takes `{user,repo}`.

```
export const Issues = React.createContext();
export default ({ children }) => {
  const [issues, setIssues] = useState([]);
  const useIssues = ({ user, repo }) => {
    useEffect(() => {
      axios
        .get(
          `https://api.github.com/repos/${user}/${repo}/issues`
        )
        .then(response => {
          setIssues(response.data);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }, [user, repo]);
    return issues;
  };
  return (
    <Issues.Provider value={{ issues, useIssues }}>
      {children}
    </Issues.Provider>
  );
};
```

The component that has all the components that need issues can import this issues provider:

```
import IssuesProvider from './IssuesProvider';
export default () => (
  <IssuesProvider>
    <ComponentThatNeedsIssues />
    <ComponentThatSetsAndGetsIssues />
  </IssuesProvider>
);
```

For a component that needs to set issues you can get useIssues from context:

```
const { useIssues } = useContext(Issues);
const issues = useIssues({user,repo});
```

For a component that only needs issues:

```
const { issues } = useContext(Issues);
```

To see it all work together there is a codepen [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/a-simple-react-router-v4tutorial-e474f)

Comment: If I put useIssues function inside my components where I want to fetch issues it gets called every time I input something in the field and not on submit

Comment: If I try to call it ```onSubmit``` I'm getting an error  ```Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component```